# Help required to compute logic of an answer.

Tags: combinations, factorial, perfect-powers

How is the sum of combination series $${20 \choose 1} + {20\choose 2} + {20 \choose 3} +\cdots +{20 \choose 20} = 2^{20}?$$
No one told me or perhaps I missed the logic behind using so in my question.

Comment: It's not , it's $2^{20}-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the expansion ,
$$(1+x)^{20}={20 \choose 0} + {20\choose 1}x + {20 \choose 2}x^2 +\cdots +{20 \choose 20}x^{20} $$

Plugging in $x=1$, we get,
$$2^{20}={20 \choose 0} + {20\choose 1} + {20 \choose 2} +\cdots +{20 \choose 20} $$
$$\implies {20\choose 1} + {20 \choose 2} +\cdots +{20 \choose 20} =2^{20}-1$$

Comment: okay sir, but thats what I am asking. From where did the $2^(20)$ and stuff came from.You rewrote my question. Any of my stupidity is deeply regretted.Please help I am a struggle.

Comment: yes sir of course. But I am afraid that it does not tell me about 20c0+20c1+..+20c20= 2^(20).

Comment: Yes. I understood everything except your last step. (=2^20 - 1)

Comment: yes. everything except how you equated it to 2^(20)-1

Comment: Oops.You are a genius sir.Thanx a ton for giving me that much time.

Comment: could you also tell me reason behind -1.As my book even didn't mention this extra minus

Comment: What's the point of calling one of the ones $x$? Using the binomial theorem to expand $(1+1)^{20}$ doesn't need any $x$s.

Comment: @user5183360 the sum starts from ${20 \choose 0}$, the first term of your series is ${20 \choose 1}$

Comment: @Nikunj oh ok got it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot one term: 20c0 in your notation.

A set having $20$ elements has in total $2^{20}$ subsets.

It has $\binom{20}{k}$ subsets with cardinality $k$ so that: $$2^{20}=\sum_{k=0}^{20}\binom{20}{k}$$